# how to use include tag for setting herder in all activity android?

Tags: android

i want toe create common template for my android application.i don't know how? some body told use include tag.I need some example for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can create first anim folder and create inside header xml file and that header xml file used in all xml file like below.

```
    <include layout="@anim/footer" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Thanks,
Nik...